# How to verify if Blobstore Files record already exists?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Looks like `get_file_name(blob_key)` can be used in accordance with [Blobstore Files API Functions doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobstorefiles?hl=en). But this is in case I know blob_key (actually, I know it, but this is additional request to datastore).

I would like to verify that the same file is not added to Blobstore second time. Filename is unique. So, can I check presence of record by file name?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot check for the filename. Every time you create or opload a file with the same name to the blobstore it will be added with te same name, but a new blob_key.

Here is some code to delete the old versions of the blob

```
..... code to create a new blob with filename = name
files.finalize(f_name)                                   # finalize the new blob                        
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(f_name)          # get the blob_key of the newly saved blob
blobs = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename = '%s'" %(name))                            
for blob in blobs :
    if blob.key() != blob_key : blob.delete()            # delete old versions of the blob
```